# Order of execution of parameters guarantees in Java?

Tags: java, operator-precedence, specifications, jls

Given the following function call in `C`:

```
fooFunc( barFunc(), bazFunc() );
```

The order of execution of `barFunc` and `BazFunc` is not specified, so `barFunc()` may be called before `bazFunc()` or `bazFunc()` before `barFunc()` in `C`.

Does `Java` specify an order of execution of function argument expressions or like `C` is that unspecified?

Comment: related question: [Order of execution of methods describing an instance and an argument in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724952/order-of-execution-of-methods-describing-an-instance-and-an-argument-in-java/13725048)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4) (on Expressions):

> 15.7.4 Argument Lists are Evaluated Left-to-Right
>
> In a method or constructor invocation
>   or class instance creation expression,
>   argument expressions may appear within
>   the parentheses, separated by commas.
>   Each argument expression appears to be
>   fully evaluated before any part of any
>   argument expression to its right.

Comment: While this is true, please please don't code in a way that makes it dependent on execution order. It's just adding complexity without adding functionality.

Comment: Indeed, "It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification." http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7

Comment: @Jon I disagree! if it is in the specification, then you can rely on it. For example, to read a rectangle from a file, I use this code: myRect = new Rectangle(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt()); It is concise and simple. A longer implementation would be unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I used that to avoid saving local variables in many places and made code shorter 1/2 lines for each funcion call in a parser :D. Avoiding many local variables (unless that creates more complex code) is usually good design too.

Comment: Joining this party a bit late, but I have a method to combine bytes to an int that I call like this: toInt(data[offset++], data[offset++], data[offset++], data[offset++]). I'm far too lazy to change this code, so I'm glad it will work.

Comment: @Jon If Java allowed temporary variable declaration prior to constructor chaining calls, I would agree with you.  However, I see no viable alternative to relying on this behavior when combining constructor chaining with complex member initialization.

Comment: @JohnHenckel Your example is fine. But imagine if instead of Rectangle you had new MyClass(...) and after a while you decide to reorder MyClass's constructor arguments; the IDE will automatically fix the usages for you but this results in a hard to find bug since the order of the argument resolution should have been preserved. You should be careful when using this.

Comment: Came here to check because I saw this in the Eclipse compiler source: `System.arraycopy(this.filenames, 0, (this.filenames = new String[length + argCount - index]), 0, length);`