# Method parameters order in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of execution of parameters guarantees in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201688/order-of-execution-of-parameters-guarantees-in-java)

If I have a Java method like:

```
    public void func(byte b, byte c) {...}
```

And I use it like this:

```
    a = 0;
    func(a++, a);
```

Wich parameter is passed first? Because if i'm not wrong, if it's the left one then b = 0 and c = 1. And if it's the right one then b = 0 and c = 0?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, but the benefit is near zero. I'd not recommend writing code like this, because it's highly unclear – otherwise you wouldn't have asked. But it shouldn't be that hard to find a solution.

Comment: 1) I would not want to see this code in production. 2) Test it. Then you'll know.

Comment: It's not "passed first", it's "evaluated when". They're passed at the same "time".

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, it was just an existential question :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arguments are evaluated left to right, [as specified in the JLS - section 15.7.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4).

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted to hear