# Java assignment operator execution

Tags: java, string, equals, assignment-operator

In Java, I understand that assignment evaluates to the value of the right operand, so statements like `x == (y = x)` evaluate to `true`.

This code, however, outputs `false`.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    String x = "hello";
    String y = "goodbye";
    System.out.println(x.equals(x = y));
}
```

Why is this? In my understanding, it first evaluates `(x = y)`, which assigns `x` the value of `y`, and then returns the value of `y`. Then `x.equals(y)` is evaluated, which should be `true` since `x` and `y` should share the same references now, but instead, I get `false`.

[image: Screenshot showing the source and that the output is "false"]

What is happening here?

Comment: I think you wanted to see result for `x.equals( y = x )`

Comment: Could the compiler inline `x` and `y`?

Comment: Are you assuming that the assignment `x = y` on the right hand side is executed *before* the `x` on the left hand side is evaluated?

Comment: @khelwood yes, that was my assumption. It must not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of execution of methods describing an instance and an argument in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724952/order-of-execution-of-methods-describing-an-instance-and-an-argument-in-java)

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181170/is-java-evaluation-order-guaranteed-in-this-case-of-method-call-and-arguments-pa) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201688/order-of-execution-of-parameters-guarantees-in-java)

Comment: @nits.kk I don't think so. OP already said they understand that `x == (y = x)` evaluates to true. The behavior of what you suggest would then be obvious...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First of all: that's an interesting question, but should never come up in "real code", as assigning to the variable you call in the very same line is confusing even if you know how it works.

What happens here is these 3 steps:

1. figure out which object to call the method on (i.e. evaluate the first `x`, this will result in a reference to the String "hello")
2. figure out the parameters (i.e. evaluate `x = y`, which will change `x` to point to the String "goodbye" and also return a reference to that String)
3. call the method `equals` on the result of #1 using the result of #2 as the parameter (which will be references to the Strings "hello" and "goodbye" respectively).

Looking at the byte code produced for that method makes it clear (assuming you're fluent in Java bytecode):

```
     0: ldc           #2                  // String hello
     2: astore_1
     3: ldc           #3                  // String goodbye
     5: astore_2
     6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     9: aload_1
    10: aload_2
    11: dup
    12: astore_1
    13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
    19: return
```

Line #9 is step 1 above (i.e. evaluates `x` and remembers the value).

Line #10-12 is step 2. It loads `y`, duplicates it (once for assigning, once for the return value of the assignment expression) and assigns it to `x`.

Line #13 invokes `equals` on the result computed in Line #9 and the result of Lines #10-12.

Comment: TL;DR: `x.equals(x = y)` => `"hello".equals(x = y)` => `"hello".equals(x = "goodbye")` => `"hello".equals("goodbye")` => `false`.

Comment: An important point to note is that [`.` has a higher precedence than `=`](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html).

Comment: This is more about evaluation order than about precedence. The parentheses make the precedence irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 38):

Good question! And the JLS has the answer...

[§15.12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1) (Example 15.12.4.1-2). Evaluation Order During Method Invocation:

> As part of an instance method invocation, there is an expression that
>   denotes the object to be invoked. This expression appears to be fully
>   evaluated before any part of any argument expression to the method
>   invocation is evaluated.

So, in:

```
String x = "hello";
String y = "goodbye";
System.out.println(x.equals(x = y));
```

the occurrence of `x` before `.equals` is evaluated first, before the argument expression `x = y`.

Therefore,  a reference to the string  `hello`  is remembered as the target reference before the local variable `x` is changed to refer to the string `goodbye`. As a result, the `equals` method is invoked for target object `hello` with argument `goodbye`, so the result of the invocation is `false`.

Answer (score 29):

It's important to remember that a `String` in java is an object, and therefore a reference. When you call

```
x.equals(...)
```

It is checking if the value at the location currently referenced by `x` is equal to what you are passing in. Inside, you are changing the value that `x` is *referencing*, but you are still calling `equals` with the *original* reference (the reference to "hello"). So, right now your code is comparing to see if "hello" is equal to "goodbye", which it clearly is not. After this point, if you use `x` again, it will result in a reference to the same value as y.

Comment: if i understand you, this: `"hello".equals((x = y))` should return `true` ?

Comment: No, because (x = y) will return the value of y, which is "goodbye". So if you did "goodbye".equals(x=y), that would return true

Answer (score 5):

`x=y` in the parenthesis means that expression `(x=y)` is now `goodbye`, while the outer x in `x.equals` holds the value `hello`

Comment: This really doesn't explain _why_ this is happening nor does it provide additional details that would be helpful for others.

Comment: Now that I read it out loud, I do tend to agree with you..the other answers are pretty verbose tho so dint edit it..

Answer (score 4):

Reimus gave the correct answer, but I'd like to elaborate.

In Java (and most languages) the convention is variable goes on the left, assignment on the right.

Let's Break it down:

```
String x = "hello";
//x <- "hello"

String y = "goodbye";
//y <- "goodbye";
```

For debugging purposes as well as code readability, it's always a good practice to split up your lines so that they only do one thing.

```
System.out.println(x.equals(x = y)); //Compound statement
```

Here, `x.equals(...)` is called on the original reference to x, or "hello", it is updated for the second reference.

I would write this as (and this will give you your expected answer):

```
x = y;
// x <- y = "goodbye"

boolean xEqualsX = x.equals(x);
// xEqualsX <- true

System.out.println(xEqualsX);
// "true"
```

Now this seems obvious that it should behave this way, but it's also really easy to see exactly what is going on in each line, which is something you should strive for.

Comment: Re: "always": there's such a thing as too much explicitness: would you recommend that `System.out.println("Bytes: "+1024*k);` be written as three statements?

Comment: @DavisHerring this is in the context of debugging. If you are trying to debug that statement, then yes, I would absolutely recommend splitting this statement into it's components. One statement for the multiplication and another for print. It allows for maximum flexibility. As a general rule of thumb, you want each line to do only one thing. It makes code more readable and more easily debug-able.

Answer (score 2):

I see the question in layman terms as `"hello".equals("goodbye")`. So it returns false.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your question in eclipse your both expression are correct.
1) x == (y = x) evaluate to true
it is true because value of x assign to y which is 'hello' then x and y compare they will 
same so result will true

2) x.equal(x = y) it is false
because value of y assign to x which is goodbye then x and x compare their value will be different so result will be false

Answer (score 1):

In java String is a class.

```
String x = "hello";
String y = "goodbye";
```

is a two different String which refer to two different value which is not same
and if you compare

```
 System.out.println(x.equals(x = y)); 
//this compare value (hello and goodbye) return true

    System.out.println(x == (y = x)); 
// this compare reference of an object (x and y) return false
```

Comment: Have you actually run this sample code? As the question states, `System.out.println(x.equals(x = y));` returns false, contrary to what your answer claims.

Answer (score -5):

It is seeing if x.equals (assign x to y, returns true always)
so basically x.equals(true)

Comment: this is just untrue, that's not how the assignment is evaluated