# Creating a point object from a user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I am supposed to read an input of 4 coordinates
Example: 0 1 1 1 (where 0 and 1 are the X and Y coordinates of the 1st point and 1 and 1 are the coordinates of the second point)
How am I supposed to store these integers in an arraylist of type Point.
Following is my approach :

```
  public class Project1 {
     private int m;
     private int n;
     private WeightedQuickUnionUF qu;
     private int[][] grid;
     private ArrayList<Point> connections;

    /**
    * initializes UnionFind structure, grid and connection list
    * @param m
    * @param n
    */
    public Project1(int m, int n){
    m=m;
    n=n;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     grid = new int[i][j];
    }
   }
 connections = new ArrayList<Point>();
 int size = m*n;
 qu = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(size);

   }

  public void read_input() 
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of pairs of connections:  ");
    int no_of_connections = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i < (no_of_connections * 4); i++){
    Point coordinates = (Point)sc.nextInt();
    connections.add(coordinates);
  }
   sc.close();
 }
```

Comment: What constructors are available for your `Point` class? It would be helpful if there was a `new Point(0, 1, 1, 1);` Then it would be all too easy to just add it to your array list

Comment: There are no constructors for the Point class

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on the Point class then. Is it a custom class? Or are you using a library

Comment: according to your comment below, you're using the Java.awt.Point class. It has *three* constructors, outlined in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom Object `TwoPoint` that holds all 4 coordinates. 
Use `java.awt.Point`.
I will suggest you to use a `HashMap<TwoPoint>` where the key will be the index of your input and value will be `TwoPoint`. 
For example , if you want to retrieve 4th input , just call `pointMap.get(4)`.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StorePoints
{
    static int  i   = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        HashMap<Integer, TwoPoints> pointMap = new HashMap<Integer, StorePoints.TwoPoints>();
        StorePoints sp = new StorePoints();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 4 coordinates: input ="+(i+1) +"out of  3");
            sp.takeInput(sc,pointMap);
        }

        System.out.println(" Enter index of coordinate  you want to see : [1-3]");
        int index=sc.nextInt();
        if(index<1||index>3)
            System.out.println("Wrong index");
        else
        System.out.println("Input index="+index+", "+pointMap.get(index-1).toString());
        sc.close();
    }

    public void takeInput(Scanner sc,HashMap<Integer, TwoPoints> pointMap)
    {
        int int1=sc.nextInt();int int2= sc.nextInt();int int3= sc.nextInt();int int4= sc.nextInt();
        TwoPoints tp=new TwoPoints(int1,int2,int3,int4);
        pointMap.put(i++, tp);
    }

    class TwoPoints
    {

        Point   p1;
        Point   p2;

        public TwoPoints(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4)
        {
            p1 = new Point(int1, int2);
            p2 = new Point(int3, int4);
        }

        // getters and setters
        public Point getP1()
        {
            return p1;
        }

        public void setP1(Point p1)
        {
            this.p1 = p1;
        }

        public Point getP2()
        {
            return p2;
        }

        public void setP2(Point p2)
        {
            this.p2 = p2;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "(" + p1 + "," + p2 + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
Enter 4 coordinates: input =1out of  3
1 1 2 3
Enter 4 coordinates: input =2out of  3
2 2 3 4
Enter 4 coordinates: input =3out of  3
2 2 4 5
 Enter coordinate number you want to see : [1-3]
1
Input index=1, (java.awt.Point[x=1,y=1],java.awt.Point[x=2,y=3])
```

Answer (score 2):

As AppWork Suggested , use `java.util.HashMap` to store 4 coordinates. You can sort the map using Comparator if you need. Using `java.util.ArrayList` you cannot ensure tracking the coordinates latter.

Ther is no easy way to sort HashMap. An alternative can be to get the keys set and sort it.

```
Set<Integer> keySet =pointMap.keySet();
List <Integer> keyList=new ArrayList<Integer>(keySet);
Collections.sort(keyList);
```

Now you can iterate the HashMap using this keyList. Since the keys are integer, No need to use Comoparator. If the keys were String, a Comparator could be used instead.

Comment: This still seems a comment rather than an answer. You could write out some code using your suggested approach.

Comment: You may consider using  LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap if you need to maintain insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast `int` to `Point` like that.

If your `Point` class has a constructor `Point(int x, int y)`, then you can read both coordinates from the `Scanner` and create `Point` from them:

```
int x = sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();
Point coordinates = new Point(x, y);
```

You will need to modify your loop accordingly, so that you read the correct number of `int`s from the input.

Comment: What do you mean by the Point class ?

Comment: @user Cinnam is referring to the Java Point class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: Where would I declare my point class ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: @user2892860 You are using it in your code - don't you have it declared already? Or are you using `java.awt.Point` as Trobbins mentioned?

Comment: Where am I using it ? I am using java.awt.Point

Comment: @user2892860 Ok, then it has the constructor that I used in my answer, you can use it in your code like that.

Comment: @Cinnam Point coordinates = new Point(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()); might not work - I don't think there is any guarantee of the order of evaluation of the arguments in the calling sequence.

Comment: @FredK I didn't think of that, thanks. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201688/order-of-execution-of-parameters-guarantees-in-java it should be evaluated left to right, but it's not recommended to rely on that. I'll edit it.